# Two circles inscribed in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

The question is from the ISI 2005 entrance examination paper.

Let a quadrilateral such that the sum of a pair of opposite sides equals the sum of the other pair of opposite sides(viz. AB+CD=AD+BC) Prove that the circles inscribed in triangles ABC and ACD are tangent to each other.

Comment: _ will the incenter of the triangles ABC and ACD be the center of the two inscribed circles._

Comment: connected : https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/IncirclesInQuadri.shtml#explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we know that the distance from the vertex of a triangle to the point where the incircle is tangent is $s-a$, where $s$ is the semiperimeter and $a$ is the length of the side opposite the vertex.

Let $P_1$ be the point where the incircle of $ABC$ is tangent to $AC$, and $P_2$ the point where the incircle of $ACD$ is tangent to $AC$.

Then $AP_1 = \frac{AB+AC-BC}{2} = \frac{AD+BC-CD+AC-BC}{2} = \frac{AD+AC-CD}{2} = AP_2$, so $P_1 = P_2$. So the two incircles are both tangent to $AC$ at $P_1$, and hence are tangent to each other.

Comment: we know that the distance from the vertex of a triangle to the point where the incircle is tangent is s−a, where s is the semiperimeter and a is the length of the side opposite the vertex.  please explain this. I am getting confused with this. @SamDittmer

Comment: Geometry Revisted, by Coxeter and Greitzer, is a good reference on this sort of thing (first chapter, I think). Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be the length of the tangents from $A$, $B$, and $C$ to the incenter (Both tangents from, e.g., $A$ have same length. Ask yourself why) Then $x+y+z=s$, and $y+z=a$, so $x=s-a$.